# .htaccess redirect all request to subdirectory without change the url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've my website (www.mysite.it), I need to redirect all request on a sub folder (www.mysite.it/subfolder) but I don't want that the users can see this change.

So I added this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* newwp/ [L]
```

The redirect on the subfolder, works fine, but the link on my browser navigation bar is changed (www.mysite.it/subfolder)

Comment: @anubhava in my root folder I don't have any other .htaccess, I have one on my sub directory (the wich one where I redirect)